# Best way to get all variables from a set from a certain class

Tags: java, optimization, set

I currently work with a HashSet and want to get all values of a child Class.I currently do it like this:

```
HashSet<ChildClass> newSet = new HashSet<ChildClass>();
for (SuperClass item : getSet()) {
    if (item instanceof ChildClass) {
        newSet.add((ChildClass) item);
    }
}
return newSet
```

but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, maybe with another kind of set?

Comment: Not especially.  That's about as good as you get.

Comment: This is a code smell. Why do you need such an operation? Maybe you should be storing them in a `Map<Class, Set<SuperClass>>` or similar instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's good as is but if you're looking for a more functional style then one could do:

```
HashSet<ChildClass> newSet = 
                 getSet().stream()
                         .filter(item -> item instanceof ChildClass)
                         .map(item -> (ChildClass) item)
                         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```